# Imprimir valores de uma mesma variavel via GET PHP

Tags: php, http

Preciso imprimir na tela os valores de uma mesma variável via `$_GET`, conforme o exemplo abaixo.

```
http://localhost/sistema/cadastro_usuario.php?cod_igreja=4355&nome_user=Renan&email=renan@outlook.com&celular=67992341353&cod_depto=20&cod_depto=10&cod_depto=35
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Retirei a tag [programação-dinâmica] porque isso não tem nada a ver com programação dinâmica. As outras tags, também não, pois não é só porque você usa mysql ou html no projeto, que signifique que esta pergunta tenha a ver com isso diretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Se percebi bem podes fazer o seguinte:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $val) {
    echo $key. ': ' .$val;
}
```

Em que `$key` vai ser por exemplo `cod_igreja` e o `$val` respetivo vai ser `4355` no exemplo que deste

Para imprimir só o valor de uma, neste caso `cod_igreja`:

```
echo $_GET['cod_igreja'];
```

Answer (score 1):

A varíavel *cod_depto* está repetida. Então, só a última irá ser exibida. No caso, você precisa transformá-la em um array para passar via get, colocando o *[]*:

```
http://localhost/sistema/cadastro_usuario.php?cod_igreja=4355&nome_user=Renan&email=renan@outlook.com&celular=67992341353&cod_depto[]=20&cod_depto[]=10&cod_depto[]=35

//Então, na hora de imprimir os valores de cod_depto, você faz:

$cod_deptos = $_GET['cod_depto'];
foreach($cod_deptos as $cod_depto){
    echo $cod_depto . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu intuito é fazer a depuração do seu código, você deveria na verdade buscar configurar o uso do XDebug com o seu editor de texto de escolha, ao invés de ficar depurando na base do print.

- PHPStorm - creio que vem junto
- Visual Studio Code - Instalar o plugin
- Sublime Text - Instalar o plugin. A integração no Sublime é meio estranha, porém.

Pra debug na base lusitana tem o `var_dump()` e o `print_r()`.